# How to deploy Uppy companion app to Firebase

Tags: firebase, uppy

This migth be silly question but I have very little knowledge of node.js, firebase and devops at overall.

I'm trying to host Uppy Companion app in the Firebase hosting: https://uppy.io/docs/companion/#Options

App works locally, I can deploy it to Firebase but can't access endpoint. I guess the problem is with the config and the host url or some firebase settings I'm not aware of.
That's the index.js of app:

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const companion = require("@uppy/companion");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "some-secret",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", req.headers.origin || "*");
  next();
});

// Routes
app.get("/companion", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  res.send("Welcome to Companion");
});

// initialize uppy
const companionOptions = {
  providerOptions: {
    drive: {
      key: "google drive key",
      secret: "google drive secret",
    },
  },
  server: {
    host: "localhost:3020",
    protocol: "http",
  },
  filePath: "./output",
  secret:"secret",
  debug: true,
};

const { app: companionApp } = companion.app(companionOptions);
app.use(companionApp);

// handle 404
app.use((req, res) => {
  return res.status(404).json({ message: "Not Found" });
});

// handle server errors
app.use((err, req, res) => {
  console.error("\x1b[31m", err.stack, "\x1b[0m");
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({ message: err.message, error: err });
});

companion.socket(app.listen(3020));

console.log("Welcome to Companion!");
console.log(`Listening on http://0.0.0.0:${3020}`);
```

But after deployment when I'm trying access the endpoint I get:

[image]

Can someone point me to the direction how to fix this? I guess the problem is with my configuration, not the Firebase itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Firebase Hosting can't run node apps by itself. It only serves static content.  You will have to port this to use Cloud Functions instead, then you can use Firebase Hosting to proxy requests to it.